# Postgres Query Bool Where Condition skipped

Tags: mysql, database, postgresql, laravel-7

I am looking after a project where I have encountered a query which is not working as expected. I logged the query and it's mentioned below

```
select "eoactivity"."primary_key","eoactivity"."is_active", "eoactivity"."lkdestination_primary_key", "eoactivity"."name", "eoactivity"."page_url", count(eoexperience.primary_key) as exp_count from "eoactivity"

inner join "eoactivity_mapping" on "eoactivity_mapping"."eoactivity_primary_key" = "eoactivity"."primary_key"
inner join "experience_type_mapping" on "eoactivity_mapping"."experience_type_pk" = "experience_type_mapping"."experience_type_pk"
inner join "eoexperience" on "experience_type_mapping"."experience_pk" = "eoexperience"."primary_key" and "eoexperience"."lkdestination_primary_key" = "eoactivity"."lkdestination_primary_key"

where "eoactivity"."is_active" =true and "eoactivity_mapping"."is_active" = true and "eoexperience"."is_active" = true

group by "eoactivity"."primary_key" order by "exp_count" desc limit 8
```

I can see that **where "eoactivity"."is_active" =true and "eoactivity_mapping"."is_active" = true and "eoexperience"."is_active" = true** none of these conditions are being checked. Irrespective of it being true/false, results are same.

What i have done is, I have verified the table structure and it's a boolean field and not string. Also filters work perfectly fine individually on tables. Please point me in the right direction. Thanks

Comment: So this works with a single-table `SELECT` on `eoactivity`? Break this into pieces, add in one part of the query at a time and see where it is going wrong. Start really simple, no other clauses after `WHERE`, no joins. Join one table at a time, add in other conditions and pinpoint exactly where it is going wrong.

Comment: Maybe adding table structures and data example can help to understand and identify the problem

Comment: This has been resolved guys. Sorry i forgot to update. Issue was with the other part of query